# Why is training with a SavedModel ~20x slower than training with a checkpoint for a subclassed Transformer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm experimenting with using the savedModel format because I would like to deploy the model with Tensorflow JS, but when I generate predictions with the savedModel it's about 20x slower than loading a checkpoint into a preexisting model (which is what I was doing during testing.)
Checkpoint loading here:

```
model = Transformer(num_layers=settings.num_layers,
                    d_model=settings.embed_dim,
                    num_heads=settings.num_heads,
                    dff=settings.dense_layer_units,
                    vocab_size=settings.vocab_size,
                    pe_input=settings.seq_len)
learning_rate = CustomSchedule(settings.embed_dim)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98, epsilon=1e-9)
ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(transformer=model, optimizer=optimizer)
ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, settings.checkpoint_dir, max_to_keep=5)

if ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint:
    ckpt.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)  # since we'll load the optimizer as well
    print('Latest checkpoint restored.')
```

and passing input to the model:

```
predictions, weights = model([data, False, look_ahead_mask])
```

vs. savedModel:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('Models/All/test', compile=False)
```

and passing input:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([1, None], tf.int32),
                                      tf.TensorSpec([], dtype=tf.bool),
                                      tf.TensorSpec([None, None], tf.float32)])
def model_predict(d, train, mask):
    return model([d, train, mask])  # , dec_mask])

predictions, weights = model_predict([data, False, look_ahead_mask])
```

I'm running both on the GPU, and I did try passing input to the model in the first way for the savedModel but that just made it even slower due to retracing.

Here's the full code for the model (a lot of which is adapted from the TensorFlow tutorial mentioned in the comment in the code.)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


# from 'Transformer model for language understanding' https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer
def get_angles(pos, i, d_model):
    angle_rates = 1 / np.power(10000, (2 * (i//2)) / np.float32(d_model))
    return pos * angle_rates


def positional_encoding(position, d_model):
    angle_rads = get_angles(np.arange(position)[:, np.newaxis],
                            np.arange(d_model)[np.newaxis, :],
                            d_model)

    # apply sin to even indices in the array; 2i
    angle_rads[:, 0::2] = np.sin(angle_rads[:, 0::2])

    # apply cos to odd indices in the array; 2i+1
    angle_rads[:, 1::2] = np.cos(angle_rads[:, 1::2])

    pos_encoding = angle_rads[np.newaxis, ...]

    return tf.cast(pos_encoding, dtype=tf.float32)


def create_padding_mask(seq):
    seq = tf.cast(tf.math.equal(seq, 0), tf.float32)

    # add extra dimensions to add the padding
    # to the attention logits.
    return seq[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]  # (batch_size, 1, 1, seq_len)


def create_look_ahead_mask(size):
    mask = 1 - tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((size, size)), -1, 0)
    return mask  # (seq_len, seq_len)


def scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, mask):
    """Calculate the attention weights.
    q, k, v must have matching leading dimensions.
    k, v must have matching penultimate dimension, i.e.: seq_len_k = seq_len_v.
    The mask has different shapes depending on its type(padding or look ahead)
    but it must be broadcastable for addition.

    Args:
      q: query shape == (..., seq_len_q, depth)
      k: key shape == (..., seq_len_k, depth)
      v: value shape == (..., seq_len_v, depth_v)
      mask: Float tensor with shape broadcastable
            to (..., seq_len_q, seq_len_k). Defaults to None.

    Returns:
      output, attention_weights
    """

    matmul_qk = tf.matmul(q, k, transpose_b=True)  # (..., seq_len_q, seq_len_k)

    # scale matmul_qk
    dk = tf.cast(tf.shape(k)[-1], tf.float32)
    scaled_attention_logits = matmul_qk / tf.math.sqrt(dk)

    # add the mask to the scaled tensor.
    if mask is not None:
        scaled_attention_logits += (mask * -1e9)

    # softmax is normalized on the last axis (seq_len_k) so that the scores
    # add up to 1.
    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_attention_logits, axis=-1)  # (..., seq_len_q, seq_len_k)

    output = tf.matmul(attention_weights, v)  # (..., seq_len_q, depth_v)

    return output, attention_weights


def print_out(q, k, v):
    temp_out, temp_attn = scaled_dot_product_attention(
        q, k, v, None)
    print('Attention weights are:')
    print(temp_attn)
    print('Output is:')
    print(temp_out)


class MultiHeadAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads):
        super(MultiHeadAttention, self).__init__()
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.d_model = d_model

        assert d_model % self.num_heads == 0

        self.depth = d_model // self.num_heads

        self.wq = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        self.wk = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        self.wv = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)

        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)

    def split_heads(self, x, batch_size):
        """Split the last dimension into (num_heads, depth).
        Transpose the result such that the shape is (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len, depth)
        """
        x = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, -1, self.num_heads, self.depth))
        return tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])

    def call(self, v, k, q, mask):
        batch_size = tf.shape(q)[0]

        q = self.wq(q)  # (batch_size, seq_len, d_model)
        k = self.wk(k)  # (batch_size, seq_len, d_model)
        v = self.wv(v)  # (batch_size, seq_len, d_model)

        q = self.split_heads(q, batch_size)  # (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len_q, depth)
        k = self.split_heads(k, batch_size)  # (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len_k, depth)
        v = self.split_heads(v, batch_size)  # (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len_v, depth)

        # scaled_attention.shape == (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len_q, depth)
        # attention_weights.shape == (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len_q, seq_len_k)
        scaled_attention, attention_weights = scaled_dot_product_attention(
            q, k, v, mask)

        scaled_attention = tf.transpose(scaled_attention,
                                        perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])  # (batch_size, seq_len_q, num_heads, depth)

        concat_attention = tf.reshape(scaled_attention,
                                      (batch_size, -1, self.d_model))  # (batch_size, seq_len_q, d_model)

        output = self.dense(concat_attention)  # (batch_size, seq_len_q, d_model)

        return output, attention_weights


def point_wise_feed_forward_network(d_model, dff):
    return tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(dff, activation='relu'),  # (batch_size, seq_len, dff)
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)  # (batch_size, seq_len, d_model)
    ])


class DecoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, dff, rate=0.3):
        super(DecoderLayer, self).__init__()

        self.mha1 = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.mha2 = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads)

        self.ffn = point_wise_feed_forward_network(d_model, dff)

        self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm3 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)

        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, training, look_ahead_mask):  # , padding_mask):
        # enc_output.shape == (batch_size, input_seq_len, d_model)

        attn1, attn_weights_block1 = self.mha1(x, x, x, look_ahead_mask)  # (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)
        attn1 = self.dropout1(attn1, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(attn1 + x)

        # why two MHAs? Later models (e.g. GPT-2) only use one.
        # attn2, attn_weights_block2 = self.mha2(
        #     enc_output, enc_output, out1, padding_mask)  # (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)
        # attn2 = self.dropout2(attn2, training=training)
        # out2 = self.layernorm2(attn2 + out1)  # (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)

        # maybe size down and then up again with multiple ffn layers
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)  # (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model) # was out2
        ffn_output = self.dropout3(ffn_output, training=training)
        out3 = self.layernorm3(ffn_output + out1)  # (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)

        return out3, attn_weights_block1  # , attn_weights_block2


class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, target_vocab_size,
                 maximum_position_encoding, rate=0.3):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()

        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(target_vocab_size, d_model)
        self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(maximum_position_encoding, d_model)

        self.dec_layers = [DecoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, dff, rate)
                           for _ in range(num_layers)]
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, training, look_ahead_mask):  # , padding_mask):
        seq_len = tf.shape(x)[1]
        attention_weights = {}

        x = self.embedding(x)  # (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)
        x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
        x += self.pos_encoding[:, :seq_len, :]

        x = self.dropout(x, training=training)

        for i in range(self.num_layers):
            x, block1 = self.dec_layers[i](x, training, look_ahead_mask)  # , padding_mask)

            attention_weights['decoder_layer{}_block1'.format(i + 1)] = block1

        # x.shape == (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)
        return x, attention_weights


class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, vocab_size, pe_input, rate=0.1):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()

        self.decoder = Decoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, vocab_size, pe_input, rate)

        self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

    def call(self, inputs):
        inp, training, look_ahead_mask = inputs  # , dec_padding_mask = inputs
        # dec_output.shape == (batch_size, tar_seq_len, d_model)
        dec_output, attention_weights = self.decoder(inp, training, look_ahead_mask)  # , dec_padding_mask)

        final_output = self.final_layer(dec_output)  # (batch_size, tar_seq_len, target_vocab_size)

        return final_output, attention_weights


def create_masks(inp):

    # Used in the 2nd attention block in the decoder.
    # This padding mask is used to mask the encoder outputs.
    dec_padding_mask = create_padding_mask(inp)

    # Used in the 1st attention block in the decoder.
    # It is used to pad and mask future tokens in the input received by
    # the decoder.
    look_ahead_mask = create_look_ahead_mask(tf.shape(inp)[1])

    return look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask
```

Thanks so much, and have a nice day!

If it's of any relevance, I get warnings when trying to save the model:

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0723 19:37:52.691118 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <self_attention.MultiHeadAttention object at 0x0000021D137D24C8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:52.764919 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x0000021D13AAC848>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:52.766914 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x0000021D13AB7A08>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:52.774865 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <self_attention.MultiHeadAttention object at 0x0000021D13AC1A48>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:52.846703 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x0000021D13BE1688>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:52.848691 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x0000021D13BE78C8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:52.855677 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <self_attention.MultiHeadAttention object at 0x0000021D13BF3948>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:52.928455 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x0000021D13C034C8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:52.929453 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x0000021D13C086C8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:52.936461 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <self_attention.MultiHeadAttention object at 0x0000021D13C13788>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:53.075063 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x0000021D13C64288>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:53.076060 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x0000021D13C694C8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:53.084039 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <self_attention.MultiHeadAttention object at 0x0000021D13C76548>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:53.169809 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x0000021D13C86148>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:53.171804 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x0000021D13C8B388>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:53.179784 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <self_attention.MultiHeadAttention object at 0x0000021D13C964C8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:53.273533 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x0000021D13CAA148>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:53.274530 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x0000021D13CAD388>, because it is not built.
2020-07-23 19:37:55.664396: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:329] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
W0723 19:37:55.827702 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D137D3248>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.827702 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D137D67C8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.827702 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D137D6E08>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.827702 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13AA3508>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.828699 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13AC1EC8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.828699 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13AC66C8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.828699 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13AC6D48>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.828699 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13ACB448>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.829697 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13BF3E48>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.829697 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13BF7648>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.829697 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13BF7CC8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.829697 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13BFB3C8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.830694 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C13C48>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.830694 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C18408>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.830694 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C18AC8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.831692 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C1B188>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.831692 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C76A08>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.832690 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C79208>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.832690 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C79888>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.832690 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C79F48>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.833687 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C96988>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.833687 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C9B188>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.833687 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C9B848>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:37:55.833687 19792 save_impl.py:76] Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000021D13C9BEC8>, because it is not built.
W0723 19:38:00.007525 19792 deprecation.py:506] From C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1817: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
```

There also isn't anything about saving assets, which I've seen in others' logs. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: I ran into the same problem while training an NMT with Attention model. You could either remove the checkpoint saving functionality or use the Keras `ModelCheckpoint` callback. See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint?version=nightly).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Could you elaborate? I'm not having trouble with the checkpoints, it's just that when I generate predictions with the savedModel format the generation (not the loading of the model) takes about 20x as long as if I instantiate the model and then load only the weights from a checkpoint.